# How to analyze the data section of a dynamic library file?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker

I was trying to analyze why one of my `.dll` file compiled from `MSVC` consumes more than 300MB memory in `VMmap`. This is what I got from `DUMPBIN`:

```
SECTION HEADER #3
   .data name
12E441FC virtual size
  E0E000 virtual address (10E0E000 to 23C521FB)
  206C00 size of raw data
  E0C600 file pointer to raw data (00E0C600 to 010131FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write
```

Summary

```
12E45000 .data
    4000 .idata
  304000 .rdata
  1B9000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
  B09000 .text
```

From `DUMPBIN`'s report, The data section of this `.dll` file consumes more than 300MB memory and I was trying to figure out which `.lib` file is the biggest consumer.

So I analyzed all the `.lib` files created by the user. Looks like their `.data` sections are all very small, just from several bytes to several KB. There are also some system `.lib` files, e.g. `kernel32.lib`, and `user32.lib` which I didn't analyze.

So I guess my question is:

1. Since the `.dll` file is linked from the `.lib` files and some unused variables may be opted out, shouldn't the `.data` section size of this dll file smaller than the sum of the `.data` sections of all `.lib` files? If not, why? Is the size of global/static variables included in the `.obj` or `.lib` file?
2. In general, how to analyze a `.dll` file to determine where the huge memory consumption come from?

Comment: Was the .map file any help? It should contain a list of where everything is including offset/location and size.

Comment: You should specify which development platform you are using.

Comment: Object and library file formats are linker dependent; some may use the ELF standard.  I suggest you research the ELF format.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to generate a .map file and then use a tool named `amap` to analyze it and found the bottleneck.